# First "sounds" based on parents native language?

Tags: toddler, noise

Now, our second child starts making noises (he is 5 month old), I realized, that these sounds are very similar to the sounds our daughter made, when she was in that age.

The sounds are something like "irrr" and "grrr" (many rolling R's :) ), and we asked ourselves, if this is related to our language (we are german native speaker).

And, what we are really curious about, if this is the case, what are the first sounds of other languages?

Answer (score 4):

From [Subtlety of Ambient-Language Effects in Babbling: A Study of English- and Chinese-Learning Infants at 8, 10, and 12 Months](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5421641/), it seems like there is not an easily detectible language effect on infant vocalization:

> In summary, with a methodology designed to limit possible bias effects, we did not find significant differences from chance performance for language identification in our overall dataset of 1917 utterances from English- and Chinese-learning infants at 8, 10, and 12 months. The results support the conclusion that infant babbling is based primarily on vocalization patterns *common* to both of these very different ambient languages.

Comment: Thank you, for the answer. Very interesting, that there are studies about this. But a little bit disappointing, that there are no meaningful differences.